# Power expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x) ^k}$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to expend the real function $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x) ^k}$ into a power series. I know the power developpement of $\frac{1}{(1-x)}$ in the disk of convergence. Then $\frac{1}{(1-x) ^k}$ must converge ( since finite ). Thus i would conclude that the power series of $\frac{1}{(1-x) ^k}$ must coincide with it's Taylor series and finding the corresponding coefficients through derivation at 0 i would find the power series.

- Is it the right reasoning i am making ?
- In general it might not be possible to find a power series whose sum is closely related to the function in question. Since the Taylor series of $f(x)$ must not converge, how should i approach this problem so that i can find a power developpement of $f(x)$ in some convergence domain.
- In the case of holomorphic functions one says that they are analytic in the domain of definition. Is it then the Taylor series which is meant ? If so what is the most appropriate way to find it ?

I will appreciate any comment.

Comment: You know that for $|x|<1$ you have $\frac{1}{(1-x)}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n$. What do you get when you informally differentiate both sides of the previous $k-1$-times?

Comment: Why not apply the Binomial Theorem?

Comment: I get 1/(1-x) but i am not quite sure if you are saying  that i should find the Taylor series.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible approaches. If
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0}a_n z^n $$
is an analytic function in the unit ball, then:
$$ \frac{f(z)}{1-z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n z^n,\qquad A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k \tag{1}$$
by considering the Cauchy product between $f(z)$ and $\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n$. Since:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{K}\binom{n+k}{n}=\binom{n+K+1}{n+1} \tag{2}$$
is straightforward to check by induction, it follows that:
$$ [x^n]\frac{1}{(1-x)^m}=\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}.\tag{3} $$
As suggested in the comments, that can be achieved also by differentiating both sides of:
$$ \frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n \tag{4}$$
$m-1$ times, leading to:
$$ \frac{(m-1)!}{(1-z)^m}=\sum_{n\geq m-1}(m-1)!\binom{n}{m-1}z^{n-m+1} $$
then to:
$$ \frac{1}{(1-z)^m}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}z^{n}. \tag{5}$$

Comment: Would you be more precise how you will procede further if you follow the second approach ?

Comment: @ivo: answer extended.